# sketching solution to y'=sin(y) without attempting to solve?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm being asked to sketch some solution curves to$$y'=sin(y)$$

And describe it's behavior as x tend to $\infty$ without attempting to solve im also asked what would change if the initial conditions were different i.e $y(0)=0$ or $y(0)=0.1$.

I know it probably has something to do with isoclines but for the life of me where do i even start?

Comment: Plot the slope field and “go with the flow”

Comment: You could try and take a screenshot of your plot and include it here.

Comment: Hi so i tried what you said and i got something that has zero gradient at $\pi $ and at $0$ which makes sense and looks pretty go im just wondering what happens if i change the initial conditions like if y(0)=0.01 or y(0)=-0.01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with take any point in the first quadrant where the $y$ coordinate is between $0$ and $\pi$.

Rather than mark a point, mark a short line of gradient $\sin y$. So the steepest line has gradient $1$.

Repeat over and over again.

As $y\rightarrow\pi$ or $\rightarrow 0$ the gradient $\rightarrow 0$

Comment: This is known as Euler's method, just to be precise

Comment: Hi thanks this helped alot but what happens if i change the inital conditions like if y(0)=0.01 or y(0)=-0.01

Comment: You can follow the same routine in each quadrant. For each initial value of $y$ there is a unique curve which tends to the asymptote $y=k\pi$ For integer $k$